# Paypal: Which product and api to choose?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to integrate Paypal as an online payment option into my website and have been looking at their documentation and apis for days, but I can't for the life of me figure out which product should I use and which apis work with what products. It seems they have got several products like payflow, web payments pro, paypal payments pro and several others. Then they have also got orders api, payments api, nvm/soap api, JS SDK etc. Can someone suggest which product/api should I choose when I am looking at the following factors:

- Ability to pay sellers in UK and US.
- Make payments through my website, be it moving buyer to their own page, opening payment window in an iFrame or provide an access token to make payment though my backend.
- Ability to take future payments.
- Ability to programmatically cancel payments.
- Ability to programmatically refund payments.
- Subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

You need different products for different things. For future headless payments that are not recurring on a schedule, you'll have to talk to PayPal

For recurring payments on a schedule, which are called subscriptions, use https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/ . There is no SDK for this latest subscriptions API, you need to use direct API calls.

For one-type payments, use PayPal Checkout https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/ .  If you want a server API integration, here's the front-end: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server , and the two routes you'll need on your server are with the Orders V2 API to 'Set Up Transaction' and 'Capture Transaction', which have a guide here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

That should be enough to get you started

Comment: Is there any api for cancelling orders?

Comment: You can refund a payment object or cancel a subscription

Comment: Just one more thing. Do all of the above apis work in a particular product or different products? Is it possible that when I try to use above, paypal might respond that I need to get a different product like payflow/payflow pro etc depending on my location? I haven't actually started coding it, I just need to compare it with Square and Stripe and then pick one depending on the api support.

Comment: All the above are available globally, but don't include arbitrary "future payments" capability, for which you'd have to talk to PayPal as I mentioned -- depending on your location they might recommend Braintree, which is newer than Payflow. https://www.braintreepayments.com/country-selection